# How to create service account for Spinnaker

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I want to automate pipeline triggers by using fiat service account. So I follow the Spinnaker doc: https://www.spinnaker.io/setup/security/authorization/service-accounts/ Then i have trouble to run the curl command. Where should I run it? I tried to run in local machine which is installed halyard and fiat pod in Kubernetes. However, I got cannot resolve http://front50.url:8080.

Answer (score 0):

Create Role for spinnaker with role name spinnaker-role you can edit role as per you need

```
 apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Role
    metadata:
     name: spinnaker-role
     namespace: default
    rules:
    - apiGroups: [""]
      resources: ["namespaces", "configmaps", "events", "replicationcontrollers", "serviceaccounts", "pods/logs"]
      verbs: ["get", "list"]
    - apiGroups: [""]
      resources: ["pods", "services", "secrets"]
      verbs: ["*"]
    - apiGroups: ["autoscaling"]
      resources: ["horizontalpodautoscalers"]
      verbs: ["list", "get"]
    - apiGroups: [“apps”]
      resources: [“controllerrevisions”, "statefulsets"]
      verbs: [“list”]
    - apiGroups: ["extensions", "app"]
      resources: ["deployments", "replicasets", "ingresses"]
      verbs: ["*"]
```

Service account for spinnaker

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
 name: spinnaker-service-account
 namespace: default
```

Main part role binding

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
 name: spinnaker-role-binding
 namespace: default
roleRef:
 apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
 kind: Role
 name: spinnaker-role
subjects:
- namespace: default
 kind: ServiceAccount
 name: spinnaker-service-account
```

You can edit it as per your need changing statefulset adding deployments

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think this is not similar as kubernetes service account creation. The thing is this is for Spinnaker authorization. The last step for authorization is pipeline trigger. One method is using fiat service account to do that. However, when I follow Spinnaker document, I don't know where should I run the command. And I already created the spinnaker fiat service account in IAM.

Answer (score 0):

This [url](http://front50.url:8080) is just an example and won't work. You need to access it using the service that exposes front50. If you installed using Halyard, probably the service is exposed as spin-front50:8080

I ran it in halyard and used the [URL](http://spin-front50:8080)

(I know its really long time after your question :), I just happened to see this and it's better late than never.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to port-forward into the pod, and curl your localhost with the port created for that pod, during port-forwarding.